# Modify TemplatedParent from ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a problem to modify TemplatedParent from ControlTemplate. My xaml code is:

```
<RadioButton Name="source" Focusable="True">
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>                       
            <RadioButton Name="target" Focusable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Focusable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />                       
        </ControlTemplate>                  
    </RadioButton.Template>
</RadioButton>
```

When Focusable in source is changing also Focusable in target should change and Enabled in source and target should change.

For excample:

> source.Focucable = false
>
> then
>
> source.IsEnabled = false, target.IsEnabled=false, target.Focusable=false

**UPDATED**

When I tried solution proposed by Rachel, everything works fine as long as code looks like this:

```
<RadioButton Name="source" 
                 Focusable="False" 
                 IsEnabled="{Binding Focusable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                 Height="19" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"                  
                 Width="146" Margin="0,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <RadioButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <RadioButton 
                    Name="target" 
                    Focusable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Focusable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Focusable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </RadioButton.Template>
    </RadioButton>
```

Problem occurs in my real application, where I can't set binding in xaml (controls are build dynamically, and templates are reading from resources file) but only in c#.

XAML in this situation looks like this:

```
<RadioButton Name="source" 
                 Focusable="False"               
                 Height="19" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"                  
                 Width="146" Margin="0,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <RadioButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <RadioButton 
                    Name="target" 
                    Focusable="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Focusable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Focusable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </RadioButton.Template>
    </RadioButton>
```

and c#

```
Binding bindingRadio = new Binding("RadioButton.Focusable");
bindingRadio.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
source.SetBinding(RadioButton.IsEnabledProperty, bindingRadio);
```

In xaml source Focusable is set to False, so binding in c# should set IsEnabled also to false. But when I click on radio it is making checked. Where should I put this c# code to make things works as it should be (i tried Window_Load, Radio_Initialized, Radio_Loaded)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind the `IsEnabled` properties to the `Focusable` properties?

It looks like you're already binding the `Focusable` property to the template value, so just bind the `IsEnabled` property to the `Focusable` one

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Focusable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Also, I think as a shortcut for your `Focusable` binding you can use `{TemplateBinding Focusable}` instead of binding to the relative source

Comment: Rachel if you could read my question one more time, I've made some changes.

Comment: @torpederos I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do, but try setting the binding in `<RadioButton.Style>`

Comment: Mixing binding in XAML and C# didn't work for me - I don't know why.  I solved my problem by adding event handler for FosusableChanged and setting there IsEnable property.